# got "fbDidLogin" call back but session state FBSessionStateCreatedOpening

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook sdk3.1 , have created a Facebook object with code `facebookobj = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:appID andDelegate:self];` and called `[facebookobj authorize:permissions]` .

Also in the source code of Facebook.m i modified the authorize method to use `[self.session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView....]` so that my login is always using inapp-webview .

After the user enters his credentials and press login , i get the call back `- (void)fbDidLogin{........}` . in this method when i check the session state and accessToken. Sometimes i get unexpected results (access token is nil and session state is FBSessionStateCreatedOpening) , most of the times i am logged in (access token is present and state is FBSessionStateOpen).

**Is this behavior possible? If i end up in FBSessionStateCreatedOpening state , should i close the session or invalidate it ?
 I thought Facebook sdk will give me "fbDidLogin" call back only when the session state is open.**

Note: i also set the `[FBSsession setActiveSession:facebookobj.session];` in the fbDidLogin .